# Get 'N' number of consecutive weekdays from the given date

Tags: java, date

I'm currently working on a `HR system` and it has an option for `get 10 consecutive days (working days except weekends)` of leave in its leave management module. Its a J2EE application.

All I want is to `get 'N' number of consecutive weekdays from the given date`

Does anybody knows how to achieve this problem?

P.S : I'm not using any 3rd party libraries like JodaTime..

Here is my controller's code for single day leave application. It has nothing to do with the consecutive days thing. but posting this here to prove that i'm doing something serious..

```
if (action.equals("applyLeave")) {

    Leave l = new Leave();

    int userid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userid"));
    int leavetype = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("leavetype"));
    String from = request.getParameter("from"); // from time
    String to = request.getParameter("to"); // to time
    double total = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("total")); // total hours

    String r1 = request.getParameter("rep1");
    String r2 = request.getParameter("rep2");

    if (r1 == null || r1.isEmpty()) {
        r1 = "0";
    }

    if (r2 == null || r2.isEmpty()) {
        r2 = "0";
    }

    int rep1 = Integer.parseInt(r1);
    int rep2 = Integer.parseInt(r2);

    String reason = request.getParameter("reason");
    String date = request.getParameter("date");

    l.setUser(userid);
    l.setLeavetype(leavetype);
    l.setDate(date);
    l.setFrom(from);
    l.setReason(reason);
    l.setRep1(rep1);
    l.setRep2(rep2);
    l.setTo(to);
    l.setTotal(total);

    dao.saveLeave(l);

    // get manager of the department
    UserDao udao = (UserDao) ctx.getBean("udao");
    DepartmentDao ddao = (DepartmentDao) ctx.getBean("depdao");
    NotificationDao notificationDao = (NotificationDao) ctx.getBean("notificationDao");
    User u = udao.getUserByUserID(userid).get(0);
    int department = u.getDepartment();
    Department d = ddao.getDepartmentByID(department).get(0);
    int manager = d.getManager();

    // save a notification for the respective manager
    // insert notification
    String text = u.getFirstname() + " " + u.getLastname() + " has applied for a leave";
    Notification n = new Notification();
    n.setUserid(manager);
    n.setFk(dao.getLeaveID());
    n.setType(3);
    n.setText(text);
    notificationDao.saveNotification(n);

    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    res.setContentType("text/html");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonObject myObj = new JsonObject();
    myObj.add("message", gson.toJsonTree("Successfully Inserted"));
    out.println(myObj.toString());
    out.close();

}
```

Comment: @Psioniax, I've completed most of the things in the application but i'm struggling to get this consecutive days. I've searched for google for a solution but I couldn't find any..

Comment: Edit your question to include some code

Comment: @Psioniax, edited with the code

Comment: `working days except weekdays`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Date> holidays = conf.getHolidays();
List<Date> nWorkingDays = new ArrayList<>();

// get the current date without the hours, minutes, seconds and millis
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

// iterate over the dates from now and check if each day is a business day
int businessDayCounter = 0
while (businessDayCounter < n) { //You want n working days
    int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    if (dayOfWeek != Calendar.SATURDAY && dayOfWeek != Calendar.SUNDAY && !holidays.contains(cal.getTime())) {
        businessDayCounter++;
        nWorkingDays.add(cal.getTime());
    }
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
}

return nWorkingDays;
```

Adapted from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15626124/1364747

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether you require the solution in standard java (tagged with javascript namely) but I guess you could do it as follows:

```
int numberOfDays = 10;

// Get current date
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

//Repeat until all consecutive weekdays consumed
while(numberOfDays >0) {
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    if((day != Calendar.SUNDAY) && (DAY != Calendar.SATURDAY)) {
        numberOfDays--;
    }

    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY,1);
}

// Calendar now contains the date after consuming all 
// consecutive week days
return calendar;
```

*WARNING:* Haven't compiled nor run this example so might cause exceptions.